# Parsing a qt crash dump

Tags: qt, crash, crash-dumps

I'm a newbie in programming and I need help. My program is written with Qt 5.2.0 for Windows 7, and sometimes(once a day) it crashes out, and leave a crash-message, smth like this

```
**Problem signature:**   
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH   
  Application Name: myApp.exe     
Application Version: 0.0.0.0     
Application Timestamp: 532aec55     
Name of the module with the error: Qt5Gui.dll     
Version of the module with the error: 5.2.0.0     
The time stamp module with the error: 52a4b48b    
Exception Code: c0000005     
Exception Offset: 0019d47f     
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1     
Language Code: 1049     
Additional Information 1: 37db     
Additional Information 2: 37db878952683e42830e4c35b7460d37     
Additional Information 3: 7f99     
Additional Information 4: 7f99b3fed068dc22f1d51f3279b2cd49
```

Any ideas how to parse some human readable information from it? Or does somebody know other ways to catch a crash from release version of qt app?

Answer (score 0):

`Exception Code: c0000005` means that you have memory management problems (probably some dangling pointer or referencing to null pointer).

This crash report should contains more information, call stack for example, which will help to locate problem in your code.

if you run it in Linux build your code in debug mode and run it with valgrind for memory checking. I'm pretty sure it will detect source of problem.